# Install virtualenv fails because an HTML is downloaded not a tar.gz

Tags: python, curl, gzip

I follow instructions [here](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/):

However when I try to tar xvfz:

> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: Child returned status 1 tar:
>   Error is not recoverable: exiting now

this happens because apparently, I have downloaded an HTML:

`file virtualenv-16.0.tar.gz`

gives:

> virtualenv-16.0.tar.gz: HTML document, ASCII text, with no line
>   terminators

I guess the problem could be in some settings on my machine, but have no idea which ones.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the file url mentioned in the instructions, you followed is invalid and so it returns following html code instead of expected `tar.gz` file:

```
<html><head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head><body><center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center></body></html>
```

**Solution**

Try below url:
https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/bc/fa0b5347139cd9564f0d44ebd2b147ac97c36b2403943dbee8a25fd74012/virtualenv-16.0.0.tar.gz

You can refer from here:
https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/#files

Comment: use 
`curl -O https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/33/bc/fa0b5347139cd9564f0d44ebd2b147ac97c36b2403943dbee8a25fd74012/virtualenv-16.0.0.tar.gz`

Comment: @TalhaJunaid Agreed, the url needs to be replaced with this one. Same `curl` command can be used.